# Material UI error while using Grid in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Code of Login Component:

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

const Login=()=>{
    return (
        <Grid>
            <Paper>
                Sign in
            </Paper>
        </Grid>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Code for App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login';
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Login></Login>     
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Code for app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**Error**

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with your code try restart your server it will solve the issue. I am attaching a code sandbox link where you can see it running fine.

Do one thing which is recommended change your **app.js** to **index.js**

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-thompson-u1rxk?file=/src/index.js